# User cannot use extension "uuid-ossp"

Tags: postgresql, search-path, postgresql-extensions

**EDIT** : there is no need for an extension anymore. You can now generate a `uuid` with the function `gen_random_uuid()` that is available by default since PostgreSQL 14.

I am developing an application in which I decided to use UUIDs for the primary and foreign keys. For this purpose, I used the extension "uuid-ossp" which works fine in dev environment.

Now, I am installing the testing environment. The database setup is imposed by a script made by the customer. The structure is standard: admin user, application user, application namespace etc.

I can create the extension with the admin account:

```
$ psql mydb -U [admin_user]

mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION

mydb=# select uuid_generate_v4();
        uuid_generate_v4
--------------------------------------
 23e45b57-a658-41a5-8661-0cc06568eff8
```

But when I connect with the database application user, I cannot generate a uuid :

```
$ psql mydb -U [app_user]

SELECT uuid_generate_v4();

mydb=> select uuid_generate_v4();
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
```

Both admin_user and app_user are on the same database. The app_user can "see" the extension but not use it:

```
bdd3001=> select * from pg_catalog.pg_extension;
  extname  | [...]
-----------+-
 plpgsql   | [...]
 uuid-ossp | [...]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need the schema you installed the extension to in your `search_path`.

By default an extension is installed to the "current" schema at the time of installation - the current `search_path` setting of the installing role.

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

So where did you end up installing it? See [`pg_extension.extnamespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-extension.html):

```
SELECT e.extname
     , n.nspname      AS home_schema_of_extension
     , extrelocatable AS extension_can_be_relocated
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_extension e
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = e.extnamespace;

extname   | home_schema_of_extension | extension_can_be_relocated
----------+--------------------------+---------------------------
plpgsql   | pg_catalog               | f
intarray  | public                   | t
tablefunc | public                   | t
pg_trgm   | public                   | t
...
```

You can relocate an extension with [`ALTER EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterextension.html):

```
ALTER EXTENSION uuid-ossp SET SCHEMA public;
```

Related with more explanation:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)

Comment: Added 'public' to the search path. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I had this problem, I kept checking the search path of my db_user and it looked ok, I checked where the extension was installed using my admin_user and it said it was in the public schema. Turns out the default database for the admin_user is different than the one I had my db_user set up for. I used `psql -d db_user_database` and added the extension there... that did it

Comment: I also removed something that looked like `${user}` (don't remember) from my users path. Not a clue what problem that will cause down the line...

Answer (score 4):

If you run the following in `psql`

```
\dx uuid-ossp
```

You will see the schema where the extension (and the function `uuid_generate_v4`) is installed.

Make sure that

- `app_user` has the schema in his `search_path` (you can e.g. use `ALTER USER app_user SET current_schema = ...` to change this for all future sessions).
- `app_user` has the permission to execute the function (this is normally allowed by default).
- `app_user` has the `USAGE` privilege on the extension schema.

Comment: Your answer suggested me another solution which also work : `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA my_app_user_schema`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: Installing in the app_user's schema might mean that other users don't have that schema in their `search_path`. Typically *not* what you want. Extensions typically go into the `public` schema or some dedicated schema you set in the general `search_path`.